# Space around middle dot with lmodern

Tags: letterspacing, lmodern

In my document, I use the "median dot" as a punctuation mark between different parts of a word (like in « Les candidat·e·s », the purpose is to gender neutralize French).

Sadly, with the `lmodern` package, this produces a big spacing around the dots. Is there any way to reduce this spacing, hopefully without any negative `\hspace` or switching to another font?

**Edit:** I had not run enough tests. This seems actually to be a bad interaction between `lmodern` and `xfrac` (both are required to trigger the alignment problem).

Minimal example :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\begin{document}
Les candidat·e·s
\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: You can use `Les candidat-e-s` if you may change the median dot.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This is the [picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/IEsmW.png) of what I get and I see no excess space. Please, add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) showing the issue.

Comment: You're right, the problem occurs when using lmodern and xfrac. MWE added above.

Comment: Since I consider `xfrac` a completely useless package, my recommendation is to get rid of it.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is not directly in `xfrac`, but rather that it loads `textcomp` which provides `\textperiodcentered` with wider sidebearings. I'm not sure why the developers of the Latin Modern fonts decided this way, but it's too late for doing something about it.

Remove the command from the list of TS1 commands and reestablish the default valid when `textcomp` is not loaded.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{textcomp} % this is the culprit!

\DeclareTextSymbolDefault{\textperiodcentered}{OMS}
\UndeclareTextCommand{\textperiodcentered}{TS1}

\begin{document}

Les candidat·e·s

\end{document}
```

[image]