# Removing horizontal space around \textperiodcentered

Tags: spacing, chemistry, mhchem

I would like to write a chemical formula, either using `\ce{}` from  the `mhchem` package or without. It contains a dot like the multiplication sign `\cdot` from math. It means that for example Li is coordinated by O.

At the moment I am using `Li\textperiodcentered OEt`, the horizontal space around the dot is massive, is there a way to get rid of it and make it behave like a normal character?

One alternative solution would be to get rid of the horizontal space around `$\cdot$`.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

I'd use the `chemformula` package – it allows to control the spacing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\begin{document}

\texttt{mhchem}: \ce{Li.O}

\texttt{chemformula}: \ch{Li.O}

\setchemformula{
  adduct-space = 0.1em % default setting is 0.1333em
}

\texttt{chemformula}: \ch{Li.O}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for helping, but I would like to get them closer together, still...

Comment: @dabozz well, then use less then 0.1em (that's just an example I used , you can even use 0pt or negative spacing!)

Comment: Oh, I was not aware of that. In the end I used -0.2em. Thanks!

Comment: This is really useful for adding the extra space lmodern and newcomputermodern add around the cdot (outlined in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/294268/7880 )